# show only custom plugin menu for custom user role user using add role hooks

Tags: wordpress, plugins, user-roles

I have created a custom user role for new users in **functions.php** like below codes:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_custom_roles' );

function add_custom_roles() {

    $student = add_role( 'student', 'Student', array(
        'read' => false,
        'assignments' => true,
    ));

    if( null !== $student ) {
        $role->add_cap( 'assignments', true);
   }

}
```

Want to allow access `student` roles only to view my custom plugin page: `assignments` but it is not working. Custom plugin is created by `add_menu_page` hook.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting close to your goal, to help yourself you could install this (https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/members/) which make capabilities handling easier, and then tweak the settings in order to obtain the menù visibility you want.

You should "clone" the minimum WP user role required to enter the backend (should be contributor if i remember good) and then add your custom permission to access plugin page

Comment: but in these plugin i couldn't get my plugins capabilities. i want these by using functions code not any other plugin thanks